# UITableView cell reuse, low Memory Warning, App Crashing in device after loading images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

**Please help me writing good code**

My Scenario:
loading image in tableview from custom image array(size can be 1-1000 or may be more)- Done
Placed Image on Button-Done (Dont know right way but working fine)
Getting Image tag with the help of button-Done
Not to load extra images in cell (suppose 4 image view in one cell and 26 images)-Done

I am Loading Images in UItableView but app only crashing in device, working fine in simulator. i have googled and found some answer on reusing cell modified my code accordingly to some extent. But i am still not sure about that image loading and crashing. Some time when the image are less it crash on scrolling and some time just after loading images in table view.
**I am close to my solution but not getting good result**. Please Help!!
Please check my code and modify it if required

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i", indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    //  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        NSInteger imageIndex = [indexPath row] * 4;
        NSInteger size = [imageArray count];

        imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80)];
        imageView1.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex];

        aButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton1 setTag:imageIndex];
        [aButton1 setImage:imageView1.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,80);

        [aButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton1];

        if (size == imageIndex +1) {
            return cell;
        }

        imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 80,80)];
        // imageView2.tag= tagValue+2000;
        imageView2.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex+1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];

        UIButton* aButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton2 setTag:imageIndex+1];
        [aButton2 setImage:imageView2.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 80,80);
        [aButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton2];

        if (size == imageIndex + 2) {
            return cell;
        }

        imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 80,80)];
        imageView3.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex+2];

        UIButton* aButton3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton3 setTag:imageIndex+2];
        [aButton3 setImage:imageView3.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton3.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 80,80);

        [aButton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton3];

        if (size == imageIndex + 3) {
            return cell;
        }
        imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 80,80)];
        imageView4.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex+3];

        UIButton* aButton4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton4 setTag:imageIndex+3];
        [aButton4 setImage:imageView4.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton4.frame = CGRectMake(240, 0, 80,80);
        [aButton4 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton4];

    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"old one");
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: use arc and load 10- 10 rows in tableview instead of loading all at a time.

Comment: First thing, only your cell allocation should come under if condition i.e.if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];} then write code for providing images to imageview and button.I am not sure why you are providing if (size == imageIndex + 3) {
            return cell;} condition?Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NuzhatZari Zari Not to load extra images in cell (suppose 4 image view in one cell and 26 images)-Done
 and ganesh manoj i cant use arc my project is not using it, please suggest some better solution

Comment: try this
`if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease]; 
}
        // remove old cell contents while scrolling.
        for(UIView *eachView in [cell subviews])
            [eachView removeFromSuperview];`
& then ur imageview, button addition code

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with this line

`NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i", indexPath.section,indexPath.row];`

Each of the row is created and none of the cells are reused except when scrolling back to already displayed cells.

A better way would be to take advantage of reuse of cells by using a identifier to give a cell back when it goes out of view and then styling it according to the requirement. More like `NSString *CellIdentifier =@"MyCellIdentifier";`

Now check the section and row for the cell and style it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think size of the image matters. Can you try loading with image of very small size say less than 5kb and see (just for testing purpose) ?